# Collabsible tree with Pie as Nodes

Tags: d3.js

I already created the collapsible tree by appending circle,rect,symbols and images.
But I want to build it and need to place pie charts on place of nodes. I am new to D3, so try to add Pie chart as place of nodes.But it is only appending to first .
Can you please let me know the way to do that.Here is what that i tried so far.

```
nodeEnter.append("svg").data([data]).attr("width", "50")
                        .attr("height", "50").append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")")
                        .selectAll("g.slice").data(pie).enter().append("g").attr("class", "slice")
                        .append("svg:path")
                        .attr("fill", function(d, i){
                        return color[i];
                        })
                        .attr("d", function (d) {

                        return arc(d);
                        });
```

I am attaching the working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/0odgqgsk/

Please modify it accordingly.
Thanks in advance.